# Parsing JSON into an object and displaying it within hierarchical spinners?

Tags: java, android, json

I am writing an application that accesses JSON files from a web host. These files contain information about different locations, facilities, etc. I'm attempting to come up with a method that allows us to quickly and easily parse the information and display it into hierarchical spinners to fine tune the information.

On the website we use a treeview, so this was my solution for mobile.

[You can find an example of the JSON output here.](http://jdhpro.com/downloads/testData.json)

I do not really know of a good, efficient way to parse everything, and what I'm doing now seems a bit cluttered, here is an example of what I'm doing currently:

```
private void generatePlants(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String aJsonString = jObject.getString("company");
        jObject = new JSONObject(aJsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("plant");

        plants = new String[jArray.length()+1];
        plants[0] = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject unitObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                plants[i+1] = unitObject.getString("plantLocation");
        }

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spnLocation);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, plants);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SolidCM", "exception", e);
    }
}

private void generateUnits(String json, int plant) {
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String aJsonString = jObject.getString("company");
        jObject = new JSONObject(aJsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("plant");
        aJsonString = jArray.getString(plant);
        Log.d("DEBUG",aJsonString);
        jObject = new JSONObject(aJsonString);
        jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("unit");

        units = new String[jArray.length()+1];
        units[0] = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject unitObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            units[i+1] = unitObject.getString("unitName");
        }

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spnView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, units);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SolidCM", "exception", e);
    }
}

private String getJson() {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://jdhpro.com/downloads/testData.json");

    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SolidCM", "exception", e);
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach would be to represent each of your JSON objects as Java classes. A popular way of doing it is with [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) although I've never used it and can't advise further on that.

You could, however, do it yourself. Start by working from the top with your "company" JSON object which would be represented by the following Java class...

```
public class Company {
    private String mCompanyId;
    private String mCompanyName;

    // Fields for address, phone, email etc

    private ArrayList<Plant> mPlantList;

    // Getters and setters here

    public Company (String jsonString) {
        // The jsonString will be the value (object) of the
        // "company" : {...} JSON name/value pair.
        // Parse the JSON for companyId, companyName, address etc
        // until you get to the "plant" : [...]" JSON array. Iterate
        // over the array creating a new Plant Java object passing in
        // the JSON object for each plant
    }
}
```

Now the "plant" JSON object...

```
public class Plant {
    private String mPlantId;
    private String mPlantLocation;
    private ArrayList<Unit> mUnitList;

    // Getters and setters here 

    public Plant (String jsonString) {
        // Do the same as the Company constructor - parse the JSON
        // for plantId and plantLocation then when you get to the
        // "unit" : [...] JSON array, iterate over it create new
        // instances of the Unit Java class passing in the JSON for
        // each JSON unit object
    }
}
```

OK, so I've stopped at Company and Plant classes but you can hopefully see the pattern. Create a Java class for Company, Plant, Unit, EquipType, Equip and have each of them parse their own JSON.

Now comes to the `Spinner` part. An `ArrayAdapter` can be used with any arbitrary object. Even if you use just a single `TextView` as the `Spinner` item views, you can simply override the `toString()` method of the classes to allow the `ArrayAdapter` to bind to the `TextViews`.

Example using the above Company Java class...

```
public class Company {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return mCompanyName;
    }
}
```

Example with an `ArrayList<Company>` (assuming you'll have more than one company)...

```
ArrayList<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>;

// Parse your JSON and add the companies to the ArrayList

ArrayAdapter<Company> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Company>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, companyList);
```